# Make content container div stretch when content is small/empty

Tags: html, css

I am currently working on a website where sometimes (for instance when the loading square comes up - like image below) the main content div is too small to fill the entire page with the footer/header.

I would like the main content that is in between the header and footer to stretch when the content div is too small, so that it fills the entire screen, while keeping the footer and header in view.

I have tried many different ways to do this, but all to no avail so far. The image below illustrates my problem.

The HTML layout looks like this:

```
<body>
  <div class="nav-container"></div>
  <div class="main-container"></div>
  <footer></footer>
</body>
```

[image: page where full screen not filled]

Comment: Do you really want to stretch your content div, or do you want to fix your footer to the bottom of the page?

Comment: Probably might be a better idea to fix the footer to the bottom of the page. As long as it removes the whitespace @ecg8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are familiar with flexbox, this would do the trick:

```
<body>
  <header></header>
  <div class="main-container"> Main content </div>
  <footer></footer>
</body> 

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header, footer {
  flex: none;
}

.main-container {
  flex: auto;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to do anything to fix it for me. I am using css grid (bootstrap) anyway, so I don't know how well flexbox and css grid will work together.

Comment: Code edited. It should work regardless whether you are using bootstrap or not. Also we are using flexbox here on the higher level wrapper elements e.g. body, container. Here is the pin anyway: https://codepen.io/hamzaisaac/pen/RMRMGW